# How to execute a function only after a request.execute to gapi.client.youtube has completed?

Tags: javascript, youtube-api

I am trying to get results from multiple pages of a youtube playlist. The problem is that I cannot get my second request (for the second page) to execute only after I have received the data from the first one. I've tried promises, deferrals, callbacks, and nothing seems to work.

```
function requestVideoPlaylist(playlistId, pageToken, pages) {
  $('#video-container').html('');
  var requestOptions = {
    playlistId: playlistId,
    part: 'snippet',
    maxResults: 10
  };
  if (typeof(pages)==='undefined') {
    pages = 2;
  }

  var i = 0
  while (i++ < pages){
    var request = gapi.client.youtube.playlistItems.list(requestOptions);
    request.execute(function(response) {

      nextPageToken = response.result.nextPageToken;

      var playlistItems = response.result.items;    
      console.log(playlistItems)

      if (playlistItems) {
        $.each(playlistItems, function(index, item) {
          displayResult(item.snippet);
        });
      } else {
        $('#video-container').html('Sorry you have no uploaded videos');
      }
    }).done(console.log('test'));

    if (nextPageToken) {
      console.log(nextPageToken)
      requestOptions.pageToken = nextPageToken;
    }
  }       
}
```

In this example I get a message *'Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'done' of undefined'* for the *.done(console.log('test))* and nothing from *console.log(nextPageToken)*, as that part also executes before the response is received.

Comment: Tried `.done(function() {// do stuff})` ?

Comment: I've even tried that in the example (except with console.log) and it doesn't work - I get **''Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'done' of undefined''**. Unless you mean something else or at another place or?

I have also tried it when I call the whole function, but the code within the .done() executes before the response has been received.

Comment: Does `request.execute` return a `Promise` ? Tried with `.then(function() {})` instead of `.done()` ? Can create stacksnippets http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/ , jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net to demonstrate ?

Comment: I cannot get the authorization to youtube to work in jsfiddle.net, but [here](http://jsfiddle.net/6tstLzkr/18/) is it. The problem seems to be with loading https://apis.google.com/js/client.js?onload=googleApiClientReady

As for .then - it doesn't work, as request.execute doesn't return a promise.

Comment: Not exactly certain about expected result ?, though able to open new `window` with `click` od link at http://jsfiddle.net/6tstLzkr/19/

Comment: The code is supposed to open a window, ask you to authenticate with youtube in that window, and then produce a list of your liked videos (which is how it works in my localhost server, too). If done/then works then it is supposed to show you twice as many of your liked videos at once (by getting the second page, too)

Comment: request.execute  doesn't return a promise, use request.then instead

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Obviously `request.execute()` does not return anything (`undefined`), much less a Promise, so stick your function call directly into the callback, like this:

```
request.execute(function(response) {
  nextPageToken = response.result.nextPageToken;

  var playlistItems = response.result.items;    
  console.log(playlistItems);

  if (playlistItems) {
    $.each(playlistItems, function(index, item) {
      displayResult(item.snippet);
    });

    loadNextPage(nextPageToken); // <--
  } else {
    $('#video-container').html('Sorry, you have no uploaded videos');
  }
});
```

As an aside, you cannot do `.done(console.log(...))`, as that is equivalent to:

```
var foo = console.log(...);
getAPromise().done(foo);
```

and `foo` is whatever `console.log()` returns, which in this case is `undefined`, so you're calling `.done(undefined)` which obviously won't do what you mean. Instead, you need to do something like what guest271314 suggested:

```
getAPromise().done(function(arg) {
  console.log(arg);
});
```

(As an aside to *that*, I suggest you [go read a JS book](https://github.com/getify/You-Dont-Know-JS) to strengthen your understanding of typical patterns such as this.)